# How can I debug an embedded process?

Tags: c, linux, debugging, embedded

I have a problem with debugging a process on arm + Linux platform:

This is a daemon process working with CAPWAP protocol, so it continuously communicates with another remote process. When it crashes with a segmentation fault, my usual means of debugging is to add some log output via `printf`, to find where the process has crashed, but it's not very efficient.

Is there any other way to debug this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also enable [core(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html) dump, then use `gdb` post-mortem on that core with

```
  gdb yourprogram core
```

To enable core dump, you need to call the [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) syscall with `RLIMIT_CORE`, usually in some parent process (e.g. the shell with `ulimit`)

BTW, you could also start your program thru `gdb` using

```
  gdb --args yourprogram argtoyourprogram
```

Don't forget to compile your program with `gcc -Wall -g`. The `-Wall` options give almost all warnings (very useful), and the `-g` produces debugging information.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options for debugging in this case.

1. Debug your program using GDB debugger. You can set breakpoints in your program using GDB.
2. Use Android-ndk for debugging your segmentation fault. This kind of debug can provide the exact location of the error.

Comment: The oriinal poster might have an embedded Linux running on ARM which is not an Android...